# Renamed folder dissapeared in Filezilla

Tags: ftp, directory, rename, filezilla

I was trying to temporarily remove a module folder using FileZilla by renaming it from ***"payu"*** to ***"/payu"***. I've used this method before in win explorer but with "!" before the name.

**Now the folder has disappeared.** :(

After doing some research I found out that using operators (/ ! - and so on) when renaming a folder in FTP causes the folder to go invisible.

Question is **how do I find my folder?** Are there any filters in FileZilla that block from view certain folder types?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLVED!**
Folder was moved to topmost folder on the structure, in my case above public_html.